# Neo4j Recursivenes in DM

Tags: recursion, neo4j, model, stack-overflow

I have recently been working on my Domain Model for  a Project where one NeoUser can own multiple NeoPosts. Each Neopost references its owner with the field called user.
Now I noticed that when I set the Neopost as an entry in the NeoUser.thisusersposts and also in the NeoImage Object as user, I get a recursive relationship and a Stackoverflow error.

The model i am trying to achive should look something like this:
[image]

NeoPost:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long postId;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 1, max = 600)
String question;

/**
 * Images that are involved in that post
 */
@NotEmpty
@Relationship(type = "STARES", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
Set<Neoimage> neoimageSet = new HashSet<>();

/**
 * User that made this post
 */
@Relationship(type = "WAS_CREATED_BY", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
NeoUser user;


/**
 * Users that somehow in a way possible described in Userinteractiontype enum
 * with this current post.
 */
@Relationship(type = "INTERACTED_WITH", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
Set<NeoInteraction> incomingInteractions = new HashSet<>();
```

NeoUser:

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue
Long nodeId;

@Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Username length has to be between 2 and 20 characters.")
@Property(name = "user")
String username;

//Relationships / Interactions that were initiated by this user with image of another user
@Relationship(type = "INTERACTED_WITH", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
Set<NeoInteraction> outgoingInteraction = new HashSet<>();

//Posts that this user created
@Relationship(type = "OWNS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
Set<NeoPost> thisusersposts = new HashSet<>();

@Relationship(type = "SUBSCRIBED", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
Set<NeoUser> usersubscriptions = new HashSet<>();
```

What I am asking now:

Is there some annotation that prevents this recursiveness and therefore the Stackoverflow error? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution to my problem.
After hours of debugging, I eleminated the circular reference in the hashcode by excluding the user in the NeoPost using the Lombok annotation:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "user")
```